# Springboot - Save entity in 'normal' class

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm pretty new to Springboot and Java in general and because we got this in school I'm fiddeling arround.

I'm now trying to save an entity outside of the Springboot Entities, Repositories or RestController with the following code:

InfMApplication.java:

```
package com.domain.springboot;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.domain.springboot.repositories.MovieRepository;
import com.domain.springboot.services.MovieImport;

@SpringBootApplication
public class InfMApplication {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InfMApplication.class, args);
        MovieImport movieImport = new MovieImport();
        movieImport.saveToDb();
    }
    
}
```

MovieImport.java:

```
package com.domain.springboot.services;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest.BodyPublishers;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandlers;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import com.domain.omdbapi.entities.Movie;
import com.domain.omdbapi.entities.SearchResponse;
import com.domain.omdbapi.entities.SearchResult;
import com.domain.springboot.repositories.ComplexRepository;
import com.domain.springboot.repositories.DocumentRepository;
import com.domain.springboot.repositories.MovieRepository;
import com.domain.springboot.repositories.SimpleRepository;

@Service
public class MovieImport {
    
    private final MovieRepository movieRepository;
    
    public MovieImport(MovieRepository movieRepository){
          this.movieRepository =  movieRepository;
        }
    
    public void main() {
        String randomImdbId = fetchRandomMovie();
        Movie movie = fetchMovieDetails(randomImdbId);
        saveToDb(movie);
    }
    
    public void saveToDb(Movie movie) {
        com.domain.springboot.entities.Movie springbootMovie = new com.domain.springboot.entities.Movie(movie.Title, movie.imdbID);
        this.movieRepository.save(springbootMovie);
        
        
    }
    
    public String fetchRandomMovie() {
        String randomWord = getRandomWord();
        String url = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=<API_KEY>&type=movie&s=" + randomWord;
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(
                URI.create(url))
            .header("accept", "application/json")
            .build();
        
        HttpResponse<String> response = null;

        try {
            response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        SearchResponse searchResponse = gson.fromJson(response.body(), SearchResponse.class);
        
        int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(0, searchResponse.getSearch().length);
        SearchResult randomResult = searchResponse.getSearch()[randomIndex];
        
        return randomResult.getImdbID();
    }
    
    
    public Movie fetchMovieDetails(String imdbId) {
        String url = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=<API_KEY>&type=movie&plot=full&i=" + imdbId;
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(
                URI.create(url))
            .header("accept", "application/json")
            .build();
        
        HttpResponse<String> response = null;

        try {
            response = client.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Movie movie = gson.fromJson(response.body(), Movie.class);
        
        return movie;
    }
    
    public String getRandomWord() {
        URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Wordlist.txt");
        
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        
        try {
            File file = new File(resource.toURI());
            words =  Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(0, words.size());
        
        return words.get(randomIndex);
    }

}
```

If I use "this.movieRepository.save(movieObject);" to save a movie in the MovieRestController the same way, it works. I also tried adding the "@Autowire" annotation, but this didn't work.

I always get the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.domain.springboot.repositories.MovieRepository.save(Object)" because "this.movieRepository" is null
```

How can I get to use the movieRepository in other Java classes like in the RestControllers?

Comment: you do not use the @Autowired annotation when you inject the repository, so that might sovle it, since it is a null pointer. You might not have created the bean also for the repository, can you post your repository code too?

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "com.domain.springboot.repositories.MovieRepository.save(Object)"
> because "this.movieRepository" is null

Above is perfectly valid if we look at your following shared code.

```
public class MovieImport {
    
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;
    
    public void saveToDb() {
        // Create movie
        com.domain.springboot.entities.Movie springbootMovie = new com.domain.springboot.entities.Movie("Iron Man", "284cb8fgf");
        this.movieRepository.save(springbootMovie);
    }
}
```

You've to correct certain things in your code base.
First you're not initializing the `movieRepository` and therefore, you're getting the null pointer exception. As you've been using the springboot you can use construction injection to initialized the field by spring container. Also. this class should be scanned by spring and you should also put some annotation such as Component or Service on top of it.

Following will work if your MovieImport and MovieRepository classess will scan by springboot.

```
package com.domain;
import com.domain.omdbapi.entities.Movie;
import com.domain.springboot.repositories.MovieRepository;

@Service
public class MovieImport {
    
    private final MovieRepository movieRepository;

    public MovieImport(MovieRepository movieRepository){
      this.movieRepository =  movieRepository;
    }
    
    public void saveToDb() {
        // Create movie
        com.domain.springboot.entities.Movie springbootMovie = new com.domain.springboot.entities.Movie("Iron Man", "284cb8fgf");
        this.movieRepository.save(springbootMovie);
    }
}
```

**Updated**

```
@SpringBootApplication  
public class InfMApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private MovieImport movieImport;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InfMApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
      movieImport.saveToDb();
    }

}
```

Comment: So when I use the above code, it does not work, because in the InfMApplication, where I call the function saveToDb() by creating a new MovieImport Instance, it now wants me to pass a MovieRepository. But there is none to pass to the MovieImport.

Comment: Your code should contain interface MovieRepository extending JPA repository. Then some implementor of JPA repository such as Hibernate which talk to datastore.

Comment: The inferface does that: "public interface MovieRepository extends JpaRepository<Movie, Long>". The problem ist, that because of the constructor you added in the MovieImporter, whenever I want to call the importer, I need to pass a MovieRepository as an argument.

Comment: No, not all. I want this class to spring managed bean. That's why I added the @Service annotation. You don't need to create the object of MovieImport class by your own and then call the saveToDb() method.'

Comment: But when I want to run `MovieImport movieImport;` and then `movieImport.saveToDb();`, Eclipse tells me "The local variable movieImport may not have been initialized"

Comment: You should make your caller class as spring managed bean and do the same for MovieImport class as I did for MovieRepository in this class.

Comment: Update the question with the class from where you're invoking this.

Comment: As said before, I'm calling MovieImport from InfMApplication, which is ther Springboot entrypoint an annotated with @SpringBootApplication. I'm going to post the whole code relevant, but it is huge.

Comment: Could you explain further? I don't quite get it... I also just updated the question with the whole relevant code. (Except the interface, as it is just basic without any custom code.)

Comment: Now springboot doesn't work at all. First I had to change th Autowired-Line static and then Bootspring won't start at all now. "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: ch.lucakuehne.springboot.InfMApplication"

Comment: I think something was broken in the background. I just rebuilt the whole project with maven and now the error is "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner"